# Cannot convert from WebElement to List<WebElement>

Tags: java, generics, selenium, webdriver

```
List<WebElement> fields = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']"));
System.out.println(fields.size());
```

This my Code and the error is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to java.util.List...

Answer (score 11):

You should use `findElements` to find the list of WebElements. See API doc [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-)

`findElement` returns *single* WebElement whereas `findElements` is plural and should be the expected one in this case.

```
List<WebElement> fields = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']"));
System.out.println(fields.size());
```

Comment: Awesome. Glad it worked for you. Would you accept the answer then?